# Creating a new system user didn't create a folder in /var/mail for the user - why not?

Tags: centos, postfix, centos6

I am using postfix with virtual domains. Normally I add a system user, and then add the email to /etc/postfix/virtual.

For the latest user I added however, there was a problem, and in the maillog it said:

```
Error: open(/var/mail/user.name) failed: Permission denied (euid=504(user.name
) egid=504(user.name) missing +w perm: /var/mail, euid is not dir owner)
```

I checked /var/mail and there was no folder for *user.name*

By default, is a folder a created in /var/mail for each user that is setup? Or does postfix set this folder up?

What do I need to check to see why this folder all of a sudden is not being created? I've obviously changed something lately which has messed up the system.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says `missing +w perm`...

Whatever user you're running that command as does not have write permissions to the `/var/mail` folder, so you're not allowed to create a subfolder.

Comment: I gathered it might be something like that. But do you know why the other users I have added which have got the same permissions as this new user have had no trouble creating the folder?

Comment: Is it that postfix or dovecot doesn't have permissions?

Comment: I would assume it's postfix that's supposed to create the folder. You might want to check out the folder's current owner and permissions. If I'm remembering correctly it should be owned by the postfix daemon user, with 644 permissions (or something similar; pardon my memory, it's been a while since I looked at postfix).

Comment: I thought I would change the owner and group of the folder to dovecot, and then changed chmod to 644. This gave me permission denied for every use trying to access inbox. I appreciate your help - even though you feel rusty you sound like an expert compared to me.

Comment: Anyways, as a quick fix, I changed chmod to 777 and the user.name folder was created in /var/mail. So it is clearly a permissions issue.